# Get a list of columns and widths for a specific record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a list of properties about a given table and for a specific record of data from that table - in one result
Something like this:

Column Name , DataLength, SchemaLengthMax

...and for only one record (based on a where filter)

So what Im thinking is something like this:
- Get a list of columns from sys.columns and also the schema-based maxlength value
- populate column names into a temp table that includes (column_name, data_length, schema_size_max)
- now loop over that temp table and for each column name, fetch the data for that column based on a specific record, then update the temp table with the length of this data
- finally, select from the temp table

sound reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. That way works. Not sure if it's the best, since it involves one iteration per column along with the where condition on the source table.

Consider this, instead :

1. Get the candidate records into a temporary table after applying the where condition. Make sure to get a primary key. If there is no primary key, get a rowid. (assuming SQL Server 2005 or above).
2. Create a temporary table (Say, #RecValueLens) that has three columns : Primary_key_Value, MyColumnName, MyValueLen
3. Loop through the list of column names (after taking only the column names into another temporary table) and build sql statement shown in Step 4.
4. Insert Into  #RecValueLens (Primary_Key_Value, MyColumnName, MyValueLen) 
   Select Max(Primary_Key_Goes_Here), Max('Column_Name_Goes_Here') as ColumnName, Len(Max(Column_Name)) as ValueMyLen From Source_Table_Goes_Here
   Group By Primary_Key_Goes_Here
5. So, if there are 10 columns, you will have 10 insert statements. You could either insert them into a temporary table and run it as a loop. If the number of columns is few, you could concatenate all statements into a single batch.
6. Run the SQL Statement(s) from above. So, you have Record-wise, column-wise, Value lengths. What is left is to get the column definition.
7. Get the column definition from sys.columns into a temporary table and join with the #RecValueLens to get the output.

Do you want me to write it for you ?